# Loading text file into EditText but file gets cut off

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm loading a text file into an EditText but the file only gets partially loaded. I've tried two different files and get the same result. One file gets cut off halfway through line 35 and the other line 37. No idea why.

```
<com.mobilewebtoolkit.EditTextLineNumbers
        android:id="@+id/ide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:visibility="visible" >
```

code:

```
private void openFile(final File aFile) {
        String nullChk = et.getText().toString();
        if (!changed || nullChk.matches("")) {
            try {
                currentFile = aFile;

                getExt();

                et.setText(new Scanner(currentFile).useDelimiter("\\Z").next());
                changed = false;
                exists = true;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert.setTitle("Save first?");
            alert.setMessage("(Will be saved in the current working directory)");

            alert.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            String temptxt = et.getText().toString();

                            if (currentFile.exists()) {
                                try {
                                    saveFile(currentFile.getPath(), temptxt);
                                    currentFile = aFile;
                                    getExt();

                                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                    Log.i("NullPointer", currentFile.getName());
                                }
                                try {
                                    et.setText(new Scanner(currentFile)
                                            .useDelimiter("\\Z").next());

                                    getExt();

                                    if (extension.equals("txt")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                "Extension: " + extension,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else if (extension.equals("html")
                                            || extension.equals("htm")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                "Extension: " + extension,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else if (extension.equals("css")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                "Extension: " + extension,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else if (extension.equals("js")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                "Extension: " + extension,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else if (extension.equals("php")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                "Extension: " + extension,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else if (extension.equals("xml")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                "Extension: " + extension,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                    changed = false;
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } else {
                                saveAs(null);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            final File tempFile = aFile;
            alert.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            try {
                                et.setText(new Scanner(tempFile).useDelimiter(
                                        "\\Z").next());
                                changed = false;
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            changed = false;
                        }
                    });
            alert.setNeutralButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            changed = true;
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            alert.show();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over your Scanner until hasNext() return false to make sure the whole file is read. See more information here: [Beware of using java.util.Scanner with “/z”](http://closingbraces.net/2011/12/17/scanner-with-z-regex/)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(tempFile).useDelimiter("\\Z");

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(scanner.next());
}

et.setText(sb);
```